# TypeError: Could not compare <type 'str'> type with Series

Tags: python, pandas

I get the following error when I try to filter a Dataframe by using a string

`TypeError: Could not compare <type 'str'> type with Series`

This is my code;

```
data = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
fildata = data[(data['cat1'] == 'FALSE') & (data['cat2'] != '') & (data['cat3'] == 'FALSE')]
```

EDIT 1:

Here's how the data looks like;

```
count,word,cat1,cat2,cat3
1021,.,FALSE,,FALSE
825,the,TRUE,the,FALSE
693,and,TRUE,and,FALSE
647,of,TRUE,of,FALSE
646,",",FALSE,,FALSE
435,to,TRUE,to,FALSE
353,will,TRUE,will,FALSE
297,in,TRUE,in,FALSE
274,be,TRUE,be,FALSE
```

EDIT 2:

But why does this work?

`data1 = pd.DataFrame({'cat1':[1,2,3,4],'cat2':[2,3,1,4],'cat3':[3,1,2,4]})`

`fildata = data1[(data1['cat1'] == 1) & (data1['cat2'] != 0) & (data1['cat3']== 3)]`

This results in;

`cat1  cat2  cat3
0     1     2     3`

EDIT 3:

I guess the problem is with the type. 'cat1' & 'cat2' are of the type `'bool'`

Comment: That's very little code to be able to tell much but you're missing a closing `'` on the `data['cat3']` bit.

Comment: @Leigh added the closing `'`

Comment: I've tried the same filtering with numbers. It works. What exactly is happening here?

Comment: This worked on my toy example, can you post some code and data that reproduces the problem

Comment: At least one of the `data[]` items is probably a `Series` instance. Can you print them, or better yet, do you know how to use `pdb`?

Comment: I've added some data. Please check the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following worked for me:

```
In [114]:

temp = """count,word,cat1,cat2,cat3
1021,.,FALSE,,FALSE
825,the,TRUE,the,FALSE
693,and,TRUE,and,FALSE
647,of,TRUE,of,FALSE
646,",",FALSE,,FALSE
435,to,TRUE,to,FALSE
353,will,TRUE,will,FALSE
297,in,TRUE,in,FALSE
274,be,TRUE,be,FALSE"""
data = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp))
fildata = data[(data['cat1'] == False) & (data['cat2'].isnull() ) & (data['cat3'] == False)]
In [115]:

fildata
Out[115]:
   count word   cat1 cat2   cat3
0   1021    .  False  NaN  False
4    646    ,  False  NaN  False

[2 rows x 5 columns]
```

The problem you have is that the string `FALSE`/`TRUE` are boolean dtypes as interpreted by `read_csv`:

```
In [112]:

data.dtypes
Out[112]:
count     int64
word     object
cat1       bool
cat2     object
cat3       bool
dtype: object
```

so your comparison should be against this type and not the string `'FALSE'`

Comment: Yes sir. Just figured that out :( .. and how do I compare against a boolean type? Should this be a new question?

Comment: Replacing `data['cat1'] == 'FALSE'` with `data['cat1'] == False` might help. `not data['cat1']` may be more Pythonic

Comment: @SAnand no you can't compare arrays with `not` this will raise a `ValueError` unless you use `any` or `all` to avoid the ambiguity